# Copy jar file to multiple location with gradle

Tags: gradle

I'm working with a Spring Boot App, and I want to copy the jar files as a dependency to libs folder of multiple projects. I have all the below projects in the same dir and the jar file is located in `common` project, the jar file is located in `common/build/libs/*.jar`:

```
reward
product
membership
client
common (jar's file location)
```

I am able to copy it to a single location at a times with this below snipped script:

```
task deploy (type: Copy) {
from "build/libs/le-common-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-plain.jar"
into "${project.rootProject}/../../le-reward/libs"
```

Any help would be really appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need to copy the `common` JAR to the other projects? Are not able to simply depend on the project directly? `implementation(project(":common":))`

Comment: I'm not sure if I can answer your question. Idk why I have to do it either but that's what my Tech Lead asked me to do so. But is there a way to do such a thing?